# Do most compilers optimize MATMUL(TRANSPOSE(A),B)?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, micro-optimization

In a Fortran program, I need to compute several expressions like **M** · ***v***, **M**<sup>T</sup> · ***v***, **M**<sup>T</sup> · **M**, **M** · **M**<sup>T</sup>, etc ...
Here, **M** and ***v*** are 2D and 1D arrays of small size (less than 100, typically around 2-10)

I was wondering if writing `MATMUL(TRANSPOSE(M),v)` would unfold at compile time into some code as efficient as `MATMUL(N,v)`, where `N` is explicitly stored as `N=TRANSPOSE(M)`. I am specifically interested in the gnu and ifort compilers with "strong" optimization flags (-O2, -O3 or -Ofast for instance).

Comment: I can't say about the behaviour of compilers in general, but perhaps you may want to consider BLAS routines which do this operation instead of relying on what compilers may do under certain circumstances.

Comment: It should be possible to microbenchmark what happens, or look at the asm to see if the transpose happens as one big operation or if it calls into a BLAS function that cache-blocks the transpose along with the multiply.

Comment: At least for `ifort`, if you use recent versions of MKL, the `gemm` subroutine is very optimized for small matrices. Check out [this MKL article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-improved-small-matrix-performance-using-just-in-time-jit-code) for more details.

Comment: Some timings: https://modelingguru.nasa.gov/docs/DOC-1762

Comment: @kvantour These timings don't seem to include this transpose.

Comment: @VladimirF True, that is why I said "some timings". They give an idea of how BLAS relates to MATMUL for somewhat large matrices.

Comment: @kvantour, you're citing a 10 year benchmark.  gfortran was at version 4.1.2 released in Feb of 2007.  According to gfortran wiki, it received in-lining of `matmul` in version 6, which was released in June 2016.

Comment: Optimization by elision of transpose is an important feature offered by most compilers for more than a decade . As hinted above, it is likely tied to certain optimization settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below you find a couple of execution times of various methods.

> **system:**
>
> - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500T CPU @ 2.50GHz
> - cache size      : 6144 KB
> - RAM : 16MB
> - GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.3.1 20170216 (Red Hat 6.3.1-3)
> - ifort (IFORT) 18.0.5 20180823
> - BLAS : for gnu compiler, the used blas is the default version
>
> **compilation:**
>
> ```
> [gnu] $ gfortran -O3 x.f90 -lblas
> [intel] $ ifort -O3 -mkl x.f90
> ```
>
> **execution:**
>
> ```
> [gnu] $ ./a.out > matmul.gnu.txt
> [intel] $ EXPORT MKL_NUM_THREADS=1; ./a.out > matmul.intel.txt
> ```

In order, to make the results as neutral as possible, I've rescaled the answers with the average time of an equivalent set of operations done.
I ignored threading.

#### matrix times vector

Six different implementations were compared:

1. **manual:** `do j=1,n; do k=1,n; w(j) = P(j,k)*v(k); end do; end do`
2. **matmul:** `matmul(P,v)`
3. **blas N:**`dgemv('N',n,n,1.0D0,P,n,v,1,0,w,1)`
4. **matmul-transpose:** `matmul(transpose(P),v)`
5. **matmul-transpose-tmp:** `Q=transpose(P); w=matmul(Q,v)`
6. **blas T:** `dgemv('T',n,n,1.0D0,P,n,v,1,0,w,1)`

In Figure 1 and Figure 2 you can compare the timing results for the above cases. Overall we can say that the usage of a temporary is in both `gfortran` and `ifort` not advised. Both compilers can optimize `MATMUL(TRANSPOSE(P),v)` much better. While in `gfortran`, the implementation of `MATMUL` is faster than default BLAS, `ifort` clearly shows that `mkl-blas` is faster.

[image]
***figure 1:** Matrix-vector multiplication. Comparison of various implementations ran on `gfortran`. The left panels show the absolute timing divided by the total time of the manual computation for a system of size 1000. The right panels show the absolute timing divided by n2 × δ. Here δ is the average time of the manual computation of size 1000 divided by 1000 × 1000.*

[image]
***figure 2:** Matrix-vector multiplication. Comparison of various implementations ran on a single-threaded `ifort` compilation. The left panels show the absolute timing divided by the total time of the manual computation for a system of size 1000. The right panels show the absolute timing divided by n2 × δ. Here δ is the average time of the manual computation of size 1000 divided by 1000 × 1000.*

#### matrix times matrix

Six different implementations were compared:

1. **manual:** `do l=1,n; do j=1,n; do k=1,n; Q(j,l) = P(j,k)*P(k,l); end do; end do; end do`
2. **matmul:** `matmul(P,P)`
3. **blas N:**`dgemm('N','N',n,n,n,1.0D0,P,n,P,n,0.0D0,R,n)`
4. **matmul-transpose:** `matmul(transpose(P),P)`
5. **matmul-transpose-tmp:** `Q=transpose(P); matmul(Q,P)`
6. **blas T:** `dgemm('T','N',n,n,n,1.0D0,P,n,P,n,0.0D0,R,n)`

In Figure 3 and Figure 4 you can compare the timing results for the above cases. In contrast to the vector-case, the usage of a temporary is only advised for gfortran. While in `gfortran`, the implementation of `MATMUL` is faster than default BLAS, `ifort` clearly shows that `mkl-blas` is faster. Remarkably, the manual implementation is comparable to `mkl-blas`.

[image]
***figure 3:** Matrix-matrix multiplication. Comparison of various implementations ran on `gfortran`. The left panels show the absolute timing divided by the total time of the manual computation for a system of size 1000. The right panels show the absolute timing divided by n3 × δ. Here δ is the average time of the manual computation of size 1000 divided by 1000 × 1000 × 1000.*

[image]
***figure 4:** Matrix-matrix multiplication. Comparison of various implementations ran on a single-threaded `ifort` compilation. The left panels show the absolute timing divided by the total time of the manual computation for a system of size 1000. The right panels show the absolute timing divided by n3 × δ. Here δ is the average time of the manual computation of size 1000 divided by 1000 × 1000 × 1000.*

---

The used code:

```
program matmul_test

  implicit none

  double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: P,Q,R
  double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: v,w

  integer :: n,i,j,k,l
  double precision,dimension(12) :: t1,t2

  do n = 1,1000
     allocate(P(n,n),Q(n,n), R(n,n), v(n),w(n))
     call random_number(P)
     call random_number(v)

     i=0

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     do j=1,n; do k=1,n; w(j) = P(j,k)*v(k); end do; end do
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     w=matmul(P,v)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     call dgemv('N',n,n,1.0D0,P,n,v,1,0,w,1)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     w=matmul(transpose(P),v)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     Q=transpose(P)
     w=matmul(Q,v)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     call dgemv('T',n,n,1.0D0,P,n,v,1,0,w,1)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     do l=1,n; do j=1,n; do k=1,n; Q(j,l) = P(j,k)*P(k,l); end do; end do; end do
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     Q=matmul(P,P)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     call dgemm('N','N',n,n,n,1.0D0,P,n,P,n,0.0D0,R,n)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     Q=matmul(transpose(P),P)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     Q=transpose(P)
     R=matmul(Q,P)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     i=i+1
     call cpu_time(t1(i))
     call dgemm('T','N',n,n,n,1.0D0,P,n,P,n,0.0D0,R,n)
     call cpu_time(t2(i))

     write(*,'(I6,12D25.17)') n, t2-t1
     deallocate(P,Q,R,v,w)
  end do

end program matmul_test
```

Comment: You, sir, earned a big thank you. Not only have I a clear documented answer to my question, I also realized how I can answer future similar interrogations by myself.

Comment: @G.Fougeron added the part for the matrix multiplication.

Comment: @kvantour, thanks for re-running a benchmark.  Any chance you can include the options that were used with gfortran and ifort?

Comment: @Steve Added the requested info

Comment: There was a comment, unfortunately posted as an answer and hence deleted, that the manual method is incorrect. It actually does not make any summation so the it does less work and the result is wrong.

Comment: @Naup Thanks for this. I will rerun this using a somewhat more modern CPU and repost the results and update the answer!