# BLAS/LAPACK vs vector operations in Fortran

Tags: optimization, vector, fortran, blas

Is

```
Y(1:N) = a*X(1:N) + Y(1:N)
```

any better/worse than

```
use blas
call daxpy(N, a, X, 1, Y, 1)
```

in a modern Fortran (e.g. GCC) in terms of performance? The former syntax is definitely much more readable. Or do/can modern compilers implicitly call system-optimized BLAS in such cases?

Is the answer universal for other BLAS subroutines that can be expressed in Fortran vector expressions, and for different compilers?

There is a lot of info about BLAS routines vs basic loops. I could not find any simple answer for the question above.

Thank you!

Comment: You can always call `daxpy` through some more modern interface. E.g., `call axpy
(
x
,
y
[
,
a
]
)` at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-1-routines-and-functions/axpy.html

Comment: Unfortunately I think (and please correct me if I am wrong, I want to know) the BLAS95 interfaces are Intel specific, which limits portability.

Comment: I haven't got time to write a good answer now, but the essence will be "it depends". Some compilers might turn the vector operations into BLAS calls, others won't. Some might produce highly optimized codes, others won't. Some BLAS, indeed most, libraries will be highly optimized, but some might not be. It is very difficult to say. If it were me I would profile my code and only if the vector operations were a significant part of the run time would I  look at changing them to BLAS - the readability and maintainability aspects to me are more important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do most compilers optimize MATMUL(TRANSPOSE(A),B)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222312/do-most-compilers-optimize-matmultransposea-b)

Comment: The possible duplicate question has the accepted answer detailed enough to answer this question also.

Comment: Thank you, @JohnAlexiou! After careful reading it indeed looks like an answer. However, I would never guess so without your comment :)

Comment: @Roux - I think it is best you answer your own question, by summarizing the linked answer as it applies to your situation.